# get_comments not working properly after WordPress v4.4 update

Tags: functions, comments

I just found a wired thing on my website after v4.4 update. In my blog pages I use 2 functions to fetch comments.

First I use

```
 wp_list_comments( array( "callback" => "checkout_comment", "type" => "comment") );
```

To fetch the comments only. Then I run a count check if any trackbacks exists by using

```
$trackback_count =  get_comments( array(
                                                    'status' => 'approve',
                                                    'post_id'=> get_the_ID(), 
                                                    'type'=> 'pings', 
                                                    'count' => true)
                                                 );
```

and if the do exists the I show the trackbacks/pingsbacks like this

```
wp_list_comments( array( "callback" => "checkout_comment", "type" => "pings", "reply_text" => null, "format" => "html5") );
```

Now, after v4.4 update the comments are showing fine but the trackbacks list are not showing.

Can anyone tell me why? What I might need to change to fix this?

Comment: This is not really a question. The best thing to do is to report the issue on trac https://core.trac.wordpress.org/

Comment: To be very honest with you, I've submitted a issue on wordpress trac before and no one replied and no one cared. So, I don't think it really gonna help anyway...

Comment: I know what you mean, but issues of backward compatibility will probably get high priority during the next few days.

Comment: Its not about backward compatibility, can you tell me how to do the same in the new way?

Comment: If it worked in 4.3 and doesn't work in 4.4 then it is a backward compatibility issue

Comment: Yah! but if it is a backward compatibility issue then there might be some new wp function alternative to is right? Which is a new function does the same. I'm just asking your help to upgrade my code to new standards.